# facebook javascript - post as a page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post as the page for a page I admin

The following code may have some unnecessary bits in it, but I am trying to cover all of my bases

here is a basic html table, we are going to pull data from it and post to fb

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr><td>1 col 1</td><td>1 col 2</td><td>1 col 3</td><td>1 col 4</td><td>1 col 5</td><td>1 col 6</td><td>1 col 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2 col 1</td><td>2 col 2</td><td>2 col 3</td><td>2 col 4</td><td>2 col 5</td><td>2 col 6</td><td>2 col 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3 col 1</td><td>3 col 2</td><td>3 col 3</td><td>3 col 4</td><td>3 col 5</td><td>3 col 6</td><td>3 col 7</td></tr>
</table>
```

And the script, I have tried to comment each section with what it should be doing

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : {APP_ID_HERE}, // unique app id
      version    : 'v2.7',
      cookie     : true,
      status     : true
    });
  };

// connect to facebook
(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// set up what we are actually posting to facebook
(function($)
{
  $('tr').each(function()
  {
    var msg = $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(6)').text();
    $(this).find('td:first-of-type').append('<span class="left" onclick="fbPostIt(\'' + msg + '\')">[fb]</span>');
  })
})(jQuery);

// do the work
function fbPostIt(fbPost){
  var pageId = '{PAGE_ID_HERE}'; // facebook page id from page info

  // ensure we have permissions we need
  FB.login(function(){
    // used to get user accessToken
    var authResp = FB.getAuthResponse();

    // see what accounts user has access to
    FB.api('/me/accounts', 'get', {access_token : authResp.accessToken}, function(response){
console.log(response); // this is returning an object with the accounts
FB.api('/me/permissions', 'get', {access_token : pageAccessToken}, function(resp){console.log(resp)});
/**
 * permissions listed are "manage_pages", "publish_actions" and "public_profile"
 * all marked as "status : granted"
 */

      // find the page access token for the page we want to admin
      var pageAccessToken = ''; 
      for(i in response.data){
        if(response.data[i].id == pageId) {
          pageAccessToken = response.data[i].access_token;

          // do the actual post now
          FB.api('/' + pageId + '/feed', 'post', {
            message: fbPost,
            access_token : pageAccessToken
          }, function(info){
console.log(info);
/**
 * code    : 200
 * message : "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"
 * type    : "OAuthException"
 */
          });

        }
      }
    });
  }, { scope: 'manage_pages, publish_actions' });
}
</script>
```

I don't know if I am missing something in my app settings on facebook, or within the code, I don't see anything wrong with the code outright, but hopefully some fresh eyes can assist

When I press the button to post for the first time, facebook asks for 3 sets of permissions

- to access profile
- to post on my behalf
- to manage pages

All three I say yes to

Comment: Nice of you to down vote it without a reason why?  it is a valid question and I showed more work than anyone else who has had a similar question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posting "as Page", you need `publish_pages`, not `publish_actions`.

This is documented in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/page/feed#publish

Btw, you can improve this by using `FB.login` only if the user is not authorized, and by using `FB.getLoginStatus` on page load. For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: That was awesome, and I was so close!  Thank's for the help and I will look at the other links you provided to help clean it up